# imx8mplus dev board yocto image psplash shows dual image on mipi dsi touch display

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto, device-tree, imx8

I was trying boot yocto image with custom boot logo on imx8mplus (compulab bsp) dev board with touch display interfaced via mipi dsi port, the procedure was simple, created bbappend for psplash recipe and located custom boot logo. The boot logo was coming up but it was showing double images of custom logo. The boot logo supposed to show as single image full screen on display.

The display resolution is 1280x800 .

the fbset output of target board is

```
mode "720x600-0"
    # D: 0.000 MHz, H: 0.000 kHz, V: 0.000 Hz
    geometry 720 600 1024 1200 32
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    accel true
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,0/0
endmode
```

My Finding:
The display resolution and fbset mode values are different.

How can I change display resolution atleast for psplash while compiling yocto ?

[Display Psplash Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3C62.jpg)

Tried to boot custom logo with help of psplash on yocto. But the psplash boot logo displayed as two while booting up. [boot logo double issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGiay.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using mipi specific dtb file. The default dtb having multiple interface enabled. So issue fixed by using mipi specific dtb or disabling lvds interface.